# How to convert an XML file to rows and columns using MariaDB on Xampp?

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, xampp, mariadb

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<users>

<row Id="4" Reputation="27228" CreationDate="2008-07-31T14:22:31.317" 
DisplayName="abc" 
LastAccessDate="2017-8:19:58.113" 

WebsiteUrl="http://www.joeware.com/" Location="Nerk, NY" 

AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;I am:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;the co-    
founof &lt;a href=&quot;http://om&quot;&gt;Stack 
Ext;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;the  of &lt;a 
href=&quot;http://wwwkot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Fog 
Slt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;the creatorrman 
of the board of &lt;a href=&quot;http://trello.com&quot; 
rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Trello&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;owner 
of Taco, the most f Husky on the UWest       
Side.&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;You can find me on 
Twitter (as &lt;a href=&quot;http://twitlsky&quot; 
rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;@sky&lt;/a&gt;) or on my rarely-updated 
blog, &lt;a href=&quot;http://joecom&quot; 
rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Software&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" 

Views="69136" UpVotes="785" DownVotes="96" 

ProfileImageUrl="https://i.stam/C5gBG.jpg?s=128&amp;g=1" 
AccountId="4" />

</users>
```

I wish to convert it into rows and columns so that it can be stored in a database. I tried the following on MariaDB:

```
 LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '<path>.xml'
-> INTO TABLE mytbl(id, rep, c_date, D_name,...);
```

But it resulted in error `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version` . How do I go out to convert the xml file to a rows and tables?

I am using MariaDB on Xampp.

EDIT: version 10.1.19-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem.

See test:

File: `/path/to/file.xml`

```xml
<users>
    <row Id="4"
         Reputation="27228"
         CreationDate="2008-07-31T14:22:31.317"
         DisplayName="abc"
         LastAccessDate="2017-8:19:58.113"
         WebsiteUrl="http://www.joeware.com/"
         Location="Nerk, NY"
         AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;I am:&lt;/  p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;the co-    
founof &lt;a href=&quot;http://om&quot;&gt;Stack 
Ext;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;the  of &lt;a 
href=&quot;http://wwwkot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Fog 
Slt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;the creatorrman 
of the board of &lt;a href=&quot;http://trello.com&quot; 
rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Trello&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;owner of Taco, the most f Husky on the UWest Side.&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;You can find me on Twitter (as &lt;a href=&quot;http://twitlsky&quot; 
rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;@sky&lt;/a&gt;) or on my rarely-updated blog, &lt;a href=&quot;http://joecom&quot; 
rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Software&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;"
         Views="69136"
         UpVotes="785"
         DownVotes="96"
         ProfileImageUrl="https://i.stam/C5gBG.jpg?s=128&amp;g=1"
         AccountId="4" />
</users>
```

MariaDB Command-Line:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.19-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytbl` (
    -> `id` TEXT,
    -> `rep` TEXT,
    -> `c_date` TEXT,
    -> `D_name` TEXT,
    -> `LastAccessDate` TEXT,
    -> `WebsiteUrl` TEXT,
    -> `Location` TEXT,
    -> `AboutMe` TEXT,
    -> `Views` TEXT,
    -> `UpVotes` TEXT,
    -> `DownVotes` TEXT,
    -> `ProfileImageUrl` TEXT,
    -> `AccountId` TEXT
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.xml'
    -> INTO TABLE `mytbl` (
    -> @`Id`,
    -> @`Reputation`,
    -> @`CreationDate`,
    -> @`DisplayName`,
    -> @`LastAccessDate`,
    -> @`WebsiteUrl`,
    -> @`Location`,
    -> @`AboutMe`,
    -> @`Views`,
    -> @`UpVotes`,
    -> @`DownVotes`,
    -> @`ProfileImageUrl`,
    -> @`AccountId`
    -> )
    -> SET 
    -> `id` = @`Id`,
    -> `rep` = @`Reputation`,
    -> `c_date` = @`CreationDate`,
    -> `D_name` = @`DisplayName`,
    -> `LastAccessDate` = @`LastAccessDate`,
    -> `WebsiteUrl` = @`WebsiteUrl`,
    -> `Location` = @`Location`,
    -> `AboutMe` = @`AboutMe`,
    -> `Views` = @`Views`,
    -> `UpVotes` = @`UpVotes`,
    -> `DownVotes` = @`DownVotes`,
    -> `ProfileImageUrl` = @`ProfileImageUrl`,
    -> `AccountId` = @`AccountId`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)                  
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [_]> SELECT
    -> `id`,
    -> `rep`,
    -> `c_date`,
    -> `D_name`,
    -> `LastAccessDate`,
    -> `WebsiteUrl`,
    -> `Location`,
    -> `AboutMe`,
    -> `Views`,
    -> `UpVotes`,
    -> `DownVotes`,
    -> `ProfileImageUrl`,
    -> `AccountId`
    -> FROM
    -> `mytbl`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             id: 4
            rep: 27228
         c_date: 2008-07-31T14:22:31.317
         D_name: abc
 LastAccessDate: 2017-8:19:58.113
     WebsiteUrl: http://www.joeware.com/
       Location: Nerk, NY
        AboutMe: <p>I am:</  p>&#xA;&#xA;<ul>&#xA;<li>the co-    
founof <a href="http://om">Stack 
Ext;/a></li>&#xA;<li>the  of <a 
href="http://wwwkot; rel="nofollow">Fog 
Slt;/a></li>&#xA;<li>the creatorrman 
of the board of <a href="http://trello.com" 
rel="nofollow">Trello</a></li>&#xA;<li>owner of Taco, the most f Husky on the UWest Side.</li>&#xA;</ul>&#xA;&#xA;<p>You can find me on Twitter (as <a href="http://twitlsky" 
rel="nofollow">@sky</a>) or on my rarely-updated blog, <a href="http://joecom" 
rel="nofollow">Software</a>.</p>&#xA;
          Views: 69136
        UpVotes: 785
      DownVotes: 96
ProfileImageUrl: https://i.stam/C5gBG.jpg?s=128&g=1
      AccountId: 4
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [LOAD XML](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/load-xml/).

**UPDATE**

Check the value of the server system variable [local_infile](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#local_infile):

```
MariaDB [_]> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE `Variable_name` = 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: May be it is a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. I am on a 32-bit system and running MariaDB through Xampp. I replicated the exact steps you did and still encountered the same error.